# Loading a script before another one

Tags: 8, theming

I have created a dependency like the following, but it seems that acquia_lift is still not running before gtmscripts. How can I achieve this?

```
 GTMscripts:
 version: 1
 header : true
 js:
   assets/js/GTMscripts.js: {}
 dependencies:
    - acquia_lift/acquia_lift
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as [Replace custom weights with dependencies in library declarations](https://www.drupal.org/node/1945262) is not fixed, you have to use weights to control the priorities of JavaScript files.

```
 js:
   assets/js/GTMscripts.js: { weight: 10 }
```

Comment: Should not declaring a script as dependency of another script cause that script to be loaded first? Otherwise, it would not make sense.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes, that would make sense. But what happens, if the js file in the library acquia_lift has also a weight defined? I think there must be a reason for the issue the OP has.

Comment: Yes, there must be a reason. I pointed that out because the cases are two: Drupal doesn't load first the dependencies, or something else is wrong. I didn't mean the answer was not correct. [acquia_lift/acquia_lift doesn't set its weight](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/acquia_lift/tree/acquia_lift.libraries.yml?h=8.x-1.x), though.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: This does not work as expected because of an unsolved issue, I've added this to the answer. At the moment you have to use weight to control the priorities.

Comment: I edited the answer, since the issue needs to be fixed, for dependencies to be loaded after.

Comment: Only negative weights are allowed (but should be avoided). Instead of a positive weight, specify accurate dependencies for this library.